# Can I Alias the DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a web app (oldapp.com) that stores images in a sub-folder (oldapp.com/images) of the DocumentRoot (aka web root).  I am rebuilding the app on a different domain (newapp.com) and have created a sub-domain specifically for storing images (images.newapp.com).  While I am building, testing, and using the new app, I still need the old app to continue accessing that old image sub-folder.  All of this is being done on the same server.  I need the new sub-domain to have the same access to the images that are in the old sub-folder.

For this particular case, I do not have the option of changing the DocumentRoot directive.  I do have access to Alias and Redirect.

Can I Alias the DocumentRoot of the images.newapp.com vhost to the old sub-directory of another vhost (/var/www/vhost/oldapp.com/httpdocs/images)?

In other words, something like this in the images.newapp.com vhost block:

```
AliasMatch ^/(.*) /var/www/vhost/oldapp.com/httpdocs/images$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that, but you need to add the trailing slash to the images directory before the $1. You also need to make sure that you've got the correct access rights to the images directory, both in the filesystem and in the apache config.

Comment: I was going by the example at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html which does not have a trailing slash.  Apparently that slash was what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that in the example there was also no slash *before* the capture. By putting it first, you removed it from the reference you captured - if you'd had the slash inside the capture it would also have worked.